# Multiple threads in Python accessing same data

Tags: python, multithreading

I am wrapping a function in a decorator so that each time it is called it starts in a new thread. Like this:

```
def threaded(func):
    def start_thread(*args, **kw):
        """Spawn a new thread on the target function"""
        threading.Thread(target=func, args=args, kwargs=kw).start()
    return start_thread
```

Now I have a class whose init method I want to run each time in a separate thread with it's own data. The idea is to give it all the data it needs and my job is done when the init methods end. So I have my class like this:

```
Class CreateFigures(object):
    @threaded
    def __init__(self, options, sList):
        self.opt = options
        self.li = sList
        self.generateFigs()
        self.saveFigsToDisk()
```

I call the constructor of this class from another class with new arguments passed each time, like this:

```
CreateFigures(newOpts, newList)
```

Here newOpts and newList can change every time the CreateFigures() constructor is called. My problem is how do I safely pass data to this constructor every time I want to start a new thread. Because the way I do it currently, it is just becoming a mess with multiple threads accessing the same data at once. I tried enclosing all the statements of the CreateFigures() constructor in a with block with an Rlock object like this:

```
def __init__(self, options, sList):
    lock = threading.RLock()
    with lock:
        self.opt = options
        self.li = sList
        self.generateFigs()
        self.saveFigsToDisk()
```

Comment: I think you are creating a new `RLock` object for each thread when you need one `Lock` that each thread will attempt to acquire.

Comment: Yes that seems like a problem. But even now when I have only single `RLock()` object, it seems that creating two threads in very quick succession cause the `options` list to be mutated. And hence results in wrong data reading.

Comment: I also tried using thread local objects like this:

`localData` = threading.local()  
`localData.options` = options  
`localData.sList = sList`  

And then tried to use this data. But this also gets mutated. I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: That does sound odd, because it doesn't matter how successively close the threads are created, acquiring the lock is atomic.  Could you show more of what you have now?

Comment: Ok now I have an idea what's wrong, but don't know how to fix it. When `CreateFigures(newOpts, newList)` is called again with different values in newOpts and newList while one thread is already running, although the lock prevents the execution inside the thread, the change in values outside the constructor still reflect inside it. Is it clear what I mean?

Comment: Are you saying that when you pass your argument of `newOpts` to a thread you are being thrown off because when said thread acquires the lock the value is/can be different than the argument passed in?

Comment: I guess it is essentially what's happening. I'll try to explain further.  
    `MainThread: CreateFigures(opts1, list1)  #This starts thread1  
    #Thread-1 is running  
    MainThread: CreateFigures(opts2, list2) #The argument opts2 takes the place of the list opts1 in Thread-1`
  
Does it make any sense to you now?

Comment: If you are using locks to make changes to shared data I'm not seeing the problem.  What is it you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I posted another question here and made it simpler, please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23783656/threading-lock-in-python-not-working-as-desired