# Threading lock in python not working as desired

Tags: python, multithreading, locking

I am trying to protect data inside my thread from the main thread. I have the following code:

```
lock = threading.Lock()

def createstuff(data):
    t= threading.Thread(target=func, args=(data,))
    t.start()

def func(val):
    with lock:
        print 'acquired'
        time.sleep(2)
        print ('Value: %s, : %s'%(val, threading.currentThread().getName()))
        print 'released\n'

ags_list = ['x']

createstuff(ags_list)

rn =random.randint(5,50)
print 'random no:', rn
ags_list[0] = rn
```

It produces the Output:

```
acquired
random no: 10
Value: [10], : Thread-1
released
```

Why does changing the list in main thread cause the list inside another thread to mutate even though it is locked? What can I do to prevent it? Thanks.

Comment: If you are wanting the data to be shared, I had already mentioned in your other post you would need to use the _same_ `Lock` in _all_ the places you're mutating that data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because the lock only works out if you're using everywhere you're mutating the list, it's not a magic spell that works everywhere if you call it at only one place.

To protect the list you need to add the lock context on both threads:

```
lock = threading.Lock()

def createstuff(data):
    t= threading.Thread(target=func, args=(data,))
    t.start()

def func(val):
    with lock:
        print 'thread: acquired'
        time.sleep(2)
        print ('Value: %s, : %s'%(val, threading.currentThread().getName()))
        print 'thread released'

ags_list = ['x']


createstuff(ags_list)

with lock:
    print 'thread: acquired'
    rn =random.randint(5,50)
    print 'random no:', rn
    ags_list[0] = rn 
    print 'thread: released'
```

You could create a thread safe list such as:

```
class ThreadSafeList(list):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(ThreadSafeList, self).__init__(*args)
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
    def __setitem__(self, idx, value):
        with self.lock:
            print 'list acquired'
            super(ThreadSafeList, self)[idx] = value
            print 'list released'
```

and then use it:

```
def createstuff(data):
    t= threading.Thread(target=func, args=(data,))
    t.start()

def func(val):
    time.sleep(2)
    print ('Value: %s, : %s'%(val, threading.currentThread().getName()))

args_list = ThreadSafeList(['x'])
createstuff(args_list)
rn =random.randint(5,50)
print 'random no:', rn
args_list[0] = rn
```

of course that's only an example that needs to be completed and improved. Here I preferred to focus on the point.

Though you do not need a lock in the thread, because accessing a value from a list is (afaict) an atomic read only action, so the mutation of the list can only happen before or after the value is being accessed within the list, not as it is accessing the value. So in the end you should not have any race issue in your example.

If you were modifying the list's value, or doing a non atomic access to data, then the lock could be useful.

N.B.: in case you thought it could work any other way: the mutex mechanism (implemented through `Lock`) does not protect data, it protects two threads of execution from executing at the same time. If you assert a lock in *Thread A*, before asserting the same lock in *Thread B*, *Thread B* will wait for *Thread A* to deassert the lock until doing its job.

Comment: Thanks this helps regarding this question.

Answer (score 2):

In python `list` is passed by reference, so any changes on that `list` are reflected anywhere else that `list` is being used.

Here is a [link](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-python) to docs that might help clear a few more things up.

```
lock = threading.Lock()

def createstuff(data):
    t= threading.Thread(target=func, args=(data,))
    t.start()

def func(val):
    with lock:
        print 'acquired'
        time.sleep(2)
        print ('Value: %s, : %s'%(val, threading.currentThread().getName()))
        print 'released\n'

ags_list = ['x']
# you would need to create a copy of different copy of that list
new_ags_list = ags_list[:] #here 

createstuff(ags_list)

rn =random.randint(5,50)
print 'random no:', rn
ags_list[0] = rn
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I did not get what you meant earlier. I'm a total noob at concurrent programming.